# How can i apply more than 1 style to a single node at the same time programmatically

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am creating a calculator in JavaFX. I have a label with **fx:ID #labelResult**, styled with css. Now i added keyboard listener to the main pane. So that when i press **Left/Right** arrow key i change the background color of the #labelResult to a color from a string bgColors array. I also added a functionality to change the labels font size when **Upper/Down** arrow keys pressed. Now problem is. It seems that i can't have both effects applied at the same time. So when i have the label's background color changed and i trigger the change font size mechanism the font size effect gets applied to the label while the bg color effect resets. How can i have both effects applied at the same time?

> P.S : I used the setStyle method to apply the style in both cases in my controller.

```
 CSS (before applying styles in my controller)

#labelRESULT {  
-fx-background-color: rgba(59, 74, 107, 0.8);
-fx-font-size: 45px;
-fx-text-fill: #fff;
}
```

Controller.java

```
@FXML
private Label labelRESULT;

@FXML
private void handleKeys(KeyEvent event) {
    int size = 45;
    String keyPressed = event.getCode().toString().toUpperCase();
    switch (keyPressed) {
        case "RIGHT":
            labelRESULT.setStyle("-fx-bg-color: #" + bgColors[1]);
            break;
        case "UP":
            labelRESULT.setStyle("-fx-font-size: " + (size + 2) + "px;");
            break;
    }
}
```

Image of what happens: http://imgh.us/javafx-calc.png

> 1- before applying styles programatically
>
> 2- after changing bg color of the label
>
> 3- after changing font size of the label while bg color is changed

Comment: when you 'setStyle' you overrides all the previous styles. The better solution is to make separate css file and switch between classes.

Comment: @fabian thanks, added breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it helps if you concat the result of getStyle() (i.e. bgColor) with the additional style (i.e. fontSize) and then use setStyle() again?

**EDIT** this would be another option (set the flag to true or false at the correct place):

```
labelRESULT.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("left-right-pressed"), flag);


labelRESULT.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("up-down-pressed"), flag);
```

and define a custom pseudo class in your  css:

```
:left-right-pressed {
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
}

:up-down-pressed {
    -fx-font-size: 14;
}
```

Comment: Great!! concatenating worked just fine!! Don't know why i haven't thought of that. Again thank you =D

Comment: Just one question. Now i got another problem. Each time i change the background color or the text size the (getStyle) string gets bigger and bigger. Is it possible to replace effect of the same type. Like i want to replace the background effect with another not append the new effect each time to the stylesheet.

http://imgh.us/2016-12-14_15h31_07.png

Comment: @RafatRefai just save the state somewhere and replace the `style` based on the state. Depending on the state no, just one or both parts should be included...

Comment: maybe you can keep track of the styles you set (store them somewhere), and then, before using setStyle() again, remove the old unused styles with the String.replace() method. Or try the solution in the edit section, which is more elegant anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add/switch css-classes to your nodes.

```
JavaFXUtils.addClasses(node, "my-class-for-font");
JavaFXUtils.removeClasses(node, "my-class-for-color");
```

Comment: How can i do that. Can you provide code please? I updated my question to include a part of my controller, can you take a look?

Comment: Thank you. the other answer solved my question. But i will also try out your method and see if it works